# Android - making audio call through the internet

Tags: android, call, sip, voip

I'm developing an android application. The app should be able to make audio calls to other users using the app. I don't want to call using phone numbers, but I want them to go through the internet. Like Skype for example. Maybe using VoIP ? I don't really know.

I was reading about SIP, but I don't understand it perfectly. 
On this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html), under Requirements and Limitations it says:

> Each participant in the application's communication session must have
>   a SIP account. There are many different SIP providers that offer SIP
>   accounts.

What exactly is a SIP account ?

I was also looking for SIP providers, but I couldn't find any free ones. Does anyone know any ?

The main problem is that I want my app to be free and also I don't really want to spend any money making it. So am I able to make this app for free ?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear about your use case. You may try to use rtsp and stream the voice to a media server like Wowza and then listen to it just like you do on youtube. The user listening it may also have another session and translate his voice stream to you via an standard media server like I said before. Not exactly a phone call but... doable in android and interface may hide all the tech specifics. It *will* look like a call. I did something like this + video couple years ago for android 4.0+

Comment: This sounds promising. You said you did something like this before. I'm worried about voice delay between the users. Did you have any problems with delay ?

Comment: Unfortunately the delay is something that will exist in this case. Sources: (a) buffering; (b) network; (c) media server; (d) streaming to the end user. (a) and (c) and partially (d) will contribute the most. I think... you can make it not that huge as I had, because I also had video and in my app it was ok, so I did not try to get rid of it but something like 2s, or may be slightly less, lag will be present.